# Field name does not have a default value

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to insert a record inside the `competition` table which have this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`competition` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `country_id` INT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `link` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `id_idx` (`country_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_country_competition_country_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`country` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

my code have the following design:

```
 using (MySqlConnection connection = new DBConnection().Connect())
 {
     using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand())
     {
         command.Connection = connection;           
         command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO competition (id, country_id, name, link) " +
                        "VALUES (@id, @country_id, @name, @link)";

         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 840);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country_id", 2);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Superliga");
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@link", "https://int.soccerway.com/national/albania/super-league/20172018/regular-season/r42054/");
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
  }
```

when the code reach this line: `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

I get:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/MySQL.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
>   An exception of type 'MySQL.Data.MysqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySQL.Data.dll but was not handled in user code: 'field 'name' doesn't have a default value'.

Now the field `name` of the `competition` table is setted as `NOT NULL` so it doesn't have a default value, but I passed to the command a correct value so I don't understand why this error is displayed, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name is a [reserved keyword in MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

The best action is to change that column to a different text, but if you really want to use that then you need to put backticks around that identifier

```
command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO competition (id, country_id, `name`, link)
                        VALUES (@id, @country_id, @name, @link)";
```

Comment: I don't know what is the best database at misleading the poor programmer when they are hit by this error. 'Syntax error' is another one very unclear message for the wrong use of reserved keywords

Comment: I banged my head for hours on this, then consider that the debugging was not very simple because the app runs as a daemon on linux service, so an error message like "hey, you're using a reserved word", rather than take me off-road as "the field does not have a default value", it would have been better, much better ..